# Finding sum of a geometric series

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, infinity, geometric-series

I am asked to find the summation of $1/3^n$ from $n=5$ to infinity.

I have done the calculation: $1/(1-r)$, for $r=1/3$, and received $1.5$. As this summation starts from $5$, I subtracted $3^0, 3^-1, 3^-2, 3^-3$ and $3^-4$ from $1.5$ and got $6.17e-3$. However, apparently this answer is wrong, and so is the answer 0. 
I appreciate any help, 
thank you!

Comment: As an alternate method, note that your series, $\frac 1{3^5}+\frac 1{3^6}+\cdots=\frac 1{3^5}\times \left( 1+\frac 13+\frac 1{3^2}+\cdots\right)=\frac 1{3^5}\times \frac 32=\frac 1{2\times 3^4}$  which is the same as your result.  Why do you believe it is wrong?

Comment: Where did that $e$ come from?

Comment: @prog_SAHIL $e^{-3}$ stands for $10^{-3}$

Comment: @prog_SAHIL or rather `6.17e−3` is the way some calculators or computers display $6.17 \times 10^{-3}$ i.e. $0.00617$

Comment: @Henry, Thanks. I always thought it was something related to exponent that I didn't knew about.

Comment: @Michel Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$1,\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3^2},\frac{1}{3^3},\frac{1}{3^4} \ldots$$

You need to calculate $$S_{\infty}-S_5$$

$$=\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{3}}-\frac{1(1-\frac{1}{3^5})}{1-\frac{1}{3}}$$

$$=\frac{\frac{1}{3^5}}{\frac{2}{3}}$$

$$=\frac{1}{2\cdot{3^4}}$$

$$=\frac{1}{162}$$

Answer (score 0):

Your method is fine indeed

$$\sum_{k=5}^\infty \frac1{3^k}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac1{3^k}-\sum_{k=0}^4 \frac1{3^k}=\frac32 - \sum_{k=0}^4 \frac1{3^k}=\frac32-1-\frac13-\frac19-\frac1{27}-\frac1{81}=\frac1{162}$$

As an alternative, following the clever method suggested by [lulu](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/252071/lulu) in the comment, we have

$$\sum_{k=5}^\infty \frac1{3^k}=\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac1{3^{j+5}}=\frac1{3^5}\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac1{3^{j}}=\frac1{3^5}\cdot\frac32=\frac1{2\cdot 3^4}=\frac1{162}$$

Comment: And this is equal to $\frac1{162}$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Exactly! I've added that, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You also can use this formula, valide if $\;|x|<1$:
$$\sum_{n=N}^\infty x^n=\frac{x^N}{1-x},$$
which is a straightforward corollary of the formula for the sum of the geometric series:
$$\sum_{n=N}^\infty x^n=x^N\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n=x^N\frac1{1-x}.$$